# Conflito entre Jinja e Handlebars

Tags: python, handlebars.js, jinja2

Como faço para resolver um conflito entre o Handlebars e o Jinja, uma vez que a sintaxe de ambos são semelhantes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bom, tenho uma opção diferente e talvez seja melhor.
Que tal alterar o delimitar do jinja2?

```
class CustomFlask(Flask):
    jinja_options = Flask.jinja_options.copy()
    jinja_options.update(dict(
        block_start_string='<%',
        block_end_string='%>',
        variable_start_string='%%',
        variable_end_string='%%',
        comment_start_string='<#',
        comment_end_string='#>',
    ))

app = CustomFlask(__name__)
```

Segue link para mais detalhes -> https://gist.github.com/lost-theory/3925738

Comment: Não acho que seja uma boa ideia alterar a sintaxe do jinja2. Embora isso seja possível, prejudica a reusabilidade do código. E se você quiser transportar um template do Flask para o Django? Acredito que sua solução seja boa em pequenos projetos apenas.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode utilizar a tag `raw` que desconsiderará o que estiver dentro do bloco dela:

```
{% raw %}
  {{ title }}
{% endraw %}
```

Nesse caso, `title` não será computado pela jinja.

Outra maneira, um pouco mais suja, é utilizar uma expressão variável:

```
{{ '{{' }}title{{ '}}' }}
```

Dê uma olhada na [documentação da jinja](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#escaping) caso tenha dúvidas.